# How to validate if the Credit card is valid or not through Stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I wanted to check if the Credit card details are valid or not. Precisely not just the format but if at all that these details are valid or not. Is there a way to check that through Stripe API.

If no, is there a way to make a payment of zero dollars. Does Stripe deduct any payment charges (any additional charges) in that case?

I prefer doing this through Stripe Javascript(Node js) SDK.

Answer (score 3):

You can try "stripe.tokens.create" to create a credit card token. The code for creating the token is shown below:

```
'use strict';

const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
    number: '4242424242424242',
    exp_month: 4,
    exp_year: 2022,
    cvc: '314',
  },
});
```

This code returns the created card token if successful. Otherwise, this call raises an error.
You can read about this method at this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Payment Method (or legacy Token) on Stripe does not validate the card. Tokenization simply takes raw card details and converts them to a Payment Method/Token, it mostly just runs a Luhn check to verify if the card number is valid.

Validation occurs when you:

```
1. attach a Payment Method to a Customer
2. confirm a SetupIntent
```

After creating a Payment Method, you should attach the Payment Method to a Customer (server-side) which will validate the card immediately, and if it does not validate, throw an error, in which case you can prompt your customer to enter a new card in your mobile app.
You can get a clear idea from [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/819).